# python Batch Renames files in mac

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to write my first script.
I have been reading about python but I am stock.

I'm trying to write a script that will rename all the file names in a specific folder.
this is what I have so far:

```
import os
files = os.listdir('files_to_Change')
print (files)
```

Get all the file names from folder:

```
for i in files:
    if i == ".DS_Store":
        p = files.index(".DS_Store")
        del files[p]
```

If mac invisible file exists delete from list (maybe a mistake here).

```
for i in files:
    oldName = i
    fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(i)
    print (oldName)
    print (fileName)
    os.rename(oldName,fileName)
```

This is where I am stock, I get this error:

Output:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'File.1'
```

On the above part I'm just removing the file extension, but that is only the beginning.
I'm also trying to substitute every point by a space and make the first letter of every word a capital.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks so much

Comment: Since you are in a POSIX environment, use the shell. It was engineered with this purpose (among the others) in mind. If you are just doing this for fun or learning, well, go along :)

Comment: When you get this running, you might want to skip _all_ files that start with a period character, not just `.DS_Store`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, when you get a list of files in a `files_to_Change` directory, you get file names without the directory name:

```
>>> files = os.listdir('test_folder')
>>> print files[0]
.com.apple.timemachine.supported
```

So in order to get the full path to that file, from whereever you're in your directory tree, you should join the directory name (`files_to_Change`) with the file name:

```
import os
join = os.path.join

src = 'files_to_Change'
files = os.listdir( src )


for i in files:
    old = i
    new, ext = os.path.splitext ( old )
    os.rename( join( src, old ), join( src, fileName ))
```

Comment: I often prefer to use the [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#module-glob) module for this sort of thing because the file names it returns will contain the full path to the files if the full path to the folder is specified. i.e. `glob.glob('/folder/files_to_Change/*'`. This means not having to `join()` the components back together after the `splitext()` in this case.