# parsing the date out of a filename and append it to the beginning

Tags: macos

I have a set of files, all of them are named like

nnn-15.10.2015 18:51.m4a

I would like to put the date in a different format at the beginning so that it looks like

2015.10.15 18:51 nnn.m4a

nnn is a random text of different length

Comment: posssible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482844/python-batch-renames-files-in-mac

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python Batch Renames files in mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482844/python-batch-renames-files-in-mac)

Comment: After being made aware of my superfluous and actively harmful contributions to your questions I removed all my comments and my answer in the spirit of harm reduction and the promotion of conciseness. Should you still be interested in my proposed solution it can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Rusk85/7b9d782570e96a7c9e4389f3e0edbe7e). I apologize for all the damage I have done and I hope none of it is of the lasting kind.

Comment: Can anyone figure out what in the world is OP asking? Supposedly there were comments clarifying but none is left.

Comment: @Braiam Here is the former suggested edit, the answer in question containing all the comments as well as the reasons for rejection of the suggested edit => [Comments below solution](https://gist.github.com/Rusk85/d6db941889420906a02ddad4684b56b1)

Comment: @Braiam after seeing the big fuss about this on Meta I decided to undelete my answer along with OPs comments. As for the rough content of my 2nd rejected edit please refer to my answer on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345285/1352384). After the first flat out rejection of the first reviewer who obviously didn't bother to check the OPs further requirements he made in the comments to my answer I was fed up and reverted my 2nd review back to the initial OPs answer mid pending approval so only my final edits (the rollback in this case) can be seen. Hope this helps.

Comment: The question seems clear enough to me. Convert one format into another.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible solution.

It is written in C# based on a *crucial assumption* due to lack of more information. I have assumed that possible inputs for `nnn` are *restricted to lower- and uppercase letters*.

It is easy enough to expand this to numbers by changing the first matching group to `([a-zA-Z0-9]+\-)`. More symbols can be included as needed of course.

All this breaks as soon as you introduce a single dash (`-`), a number or any other character not part of the English standard alphabet in `nnn`.

---

### Updates

1. Added some generated input for `nnn`
2. Randomizing dates
3. Randomized length of strings including their individual length in output
4. Implemented requirement for different formatting of `DateTime`

---

```
class Program
    {
        private static Random Random = new Random();
        private static object SyncLock = new object();
        private static object SyncLockLoop = new object();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Run(40);
        }


        private static void Run(int numberOfOutputLines)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfOutputLines; i++)
            {
                Reorder(GenerateVariableLengthString(), GenerateRandomDate());
            }
        }


        private static string GenerateVariableLengthString()
        {
            lock (SyncLock)
            {
                string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
                int strMaxLength = 100;
                int strMinLength = 5;
                int maxIndex = alphabet.Length;
                string result = null;

                int actualLength = Random.Next(strMinLength, strMaxLength);
                for (int i = 0; i <= actualLength; i++)
                {
                    lock (SyncLockLoop)
                    {
                        result += alphabet[Random.Next(0, maxIndex)];
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }
        }

        private static string GenerateRandomDate()
        {
            lock (SyncLock)
            {
                Func<int, int, int> r = Random.Next;
                int day = r(1, 27);
                int month = r(1, 12);
                int year = r(1970, 2020);

                int hour = r(0, 23);
                int min = r(0, 59);
                int sec = r(0, 59);
                return new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, min, sec).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
            }
        }

        private static string FormatDateTime(string datetimeAsString)
        {
            try
            {
                return DateTime.Parse(datetimeAsString).ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex is FormatException)
                {
                    throw new FormatException(
                        $"The value {datetimeAsString} of 'dateTimeAsString has an unknown format. Aborting execution.", ex);
                }
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        private static void Reorder(string input, string dateStr)
        {
            string dateTimeOutputFormat = FormatDateTime(dateStr);
            string untouchedInput = $"{input}-{dateStr}.m4a";
            string actualInput = $"{input}-{dateTimeOutputFormat}.m4a";
            // nnn-15.10.2015 18:51.m4a
            // 2015.10.15 18:51 nnn.m4a
            string pattern = @"^([a-zA-Z]+\-)(\d{4}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\s\d{2}:\d{2})(\.)(m4a)";
            var regex = new Regex(pattern);
            var match = regex.Match(actualInput);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                var groups = match.Groups;
                var nnn = groups[1].Value.Replace("-",String.Empty);
                var date = groups[2].Value;
                var extDot = groups[3].Value;
                var extension = groups[4].Value;

                var result = $"{date.Trim()} {nnn}{extDot}{extension}";
                Debug.WriteLine($"Actual String Length: {input.Length}");
                Debug.WriteLine($"BEFORE:    {untouchedInput}");
                Debug.WriteLine($"AFTER:     {result}{Environment.NewLine}");
            }
        }
    }

    Output of Debug.WriteLine(Result):
    Actual String Length: 31
    BEFORE:    qOFpiOOhwWDApDnjAjAIEqiOrZnJjgf-18.04.1988 08:43.m4a
    AFTER:     1988.04.18 08:43 qOFpiOOhwWDApDnjAjAIEqiOrZnJjgf.m4a

    Actual String Length: 94
    BEFORE:    YmRtSpjQtvokdhAyJaFRXjAeXqQUiXjAtDlnQkyTFAFSvZcYiTJtgZYOLNwBzpIwlNRAWnIzCMlwDIJYnRLpnQutEwBdOW-11.04.2013 04:36.m4a
    AFTER:     2013.04.11 04:36 YmRtSpjQtvokdhAyJaFRXjAeXqQUiXjAtDlnQkyTFAFSvZcYiTJtgZYOLNwBzpIwlNRAWnIzCMlwDIJYnRLpnQutEwBdOW.m4a

    Actual String Length: 20
    BEFORE:    CbVkjRtNBkcdyoHDsivs-12.10.1995 16:34.m4a
    AFTER:     1995.10.12 16:34 CbVkjRtNBkcdyoHDsivs.m4a

    Actual String Length: 64
    BEFORE:    sVEtcbQLPPedZbGclzZpHMMAbloKHBkGylaRXQabIDRNnevrRSomEvYFjdsRNfdo-16.06.1999 17:00.m4a
    AFTER:     1999.06.16 17:00 sVEtcbQLPPedZbGclzZpHMMAbloKHBkGylaRXQabIDRNnevrRSomEvYFjdsRNfdo.m4a

    Actual String Length: 15
    BEFORE:    uyYHeVYnXPXTPmY-01.01.1982 09:38.m4a
    AFTER:     1982.01.01 09:38 uyYHeVYnXPXTPmY.m4a

    Actual String Length: 51
    BEFORE:    joCzDiOzGqcNUNGOTKlPubPmobHxCBGgkVpJeFsPyyiGQbskuot-19.05.1974 01:08.m4a
    AFTER:     1974.05.19 01:08 joCzDiOzGqcNUNGOTKlPubPmobHxCBGgkVpJeFsPyyiGQbskuot.m4a

    Actual String Length: 34
    BEFORE:    kCArXfKWCYxXJnsvrWSjwmIwcnhWJgRikP-11.09.1984 03:30.m4a
    AFTER:     1984.09.11 03:30 kCArXfKWCYxXJnsvrWSjwmIwcnhWJgRikP.m4a

    Actual String Length: 94
    BEFORE:    TztNwFfrbNhopSYTeoJXNnwhpNTTCgjvPmCNpJGIbEHsKTUWwWlTRfiGdmxJLmPVDMzdplDuIbVjGdwvSWwFVqDJeWJdlW-25.09.2009 16:46.m4a
    AFTER:     2009.09.25 16:46 TztNwFfrbNhopSYTeoJXNnwhpNTTCgjvPmCNpJGIbEHsKTUWwWlTRfiGdmxJLmPVDMzdplDuIbVjGdwvSWwFVqDJeWJdlW.m4a

    Actual String Length: 41
    BEFORE:    RGltQlQjYZZPcROPkaniQYtBAiLeguUoycbqllefN-13.02.2017 15:15.m4a
    AFTER:     2017.02.13 15:15 RGltQlQjYZZPcROPkaniQYtBAiLeguUoycbqllefN.m4a

    Actual String Length: 15
    BEFORE:    iZELBPDSnJSIzLc-16.02.2005 07:58.m4a
    AFTER:     2005.02.16 07:58 iZELBPDSnJSIzLc.m4a

    Actual String Length: 50
    BEFORE:    EYVivqSwRnYGWhQjNJyicBtwGbwBSYWjoKvFPstmaRSFJSPVNV-25.07.1995 15:24.m4a
    AFTER:     1995.07.25 15:24 EYVivqSwRnYGWhQjNJyicBtwGbwBSYWjoKvFPstmaRSFJSPVNV.m4a

    Actual String Length: 63
    BEFORE:    zCtTrDSqOsmMluuqmilJOMNmBNXbpJGosZpQZsInaoUACiCBCqoAksRMOhsDGRa-03.08.2018 08:12.m4a
    AFTER:     2018.08.03 08:12 zCtTrDSqOsmMluuqmilJOMNmBNXbpJGosZpQZsInaoUACiCBCqoAksRMOhsDGRa.m4a

    Actual String Length: 61
    BEFORE:    rTzXJzRnJtlwyZugdZiCbRaeGioPOEOqwYZvamJrVBxYsktaLETtcBDzSvrAk-02.06.1974 13:52.m4a
    AFTER:     1974.06.02 13:52 rTzXJzRnJtlwyZugdZiCbRaeGioPOEOqwYZvamJrVBxYsktaLETtcBDzSvrAk.m4a

    Actual String Length: 53
    BEFORE:    ZZgRqRHAucLvPndkKuoVvACFVjhScstylTaLycdlTceQJVKWYoujG-03.02.1994 10:30.m4a
    AFTER:     1994.02.03 10:30 ZZgRqRHAucLvPndkKuoVvACFVjhScstylTaLycdlTceQJVKWYoujG.m4a

    Actual String Length: 18
    BEFORE:    JPxbInkWmsLIrcbsvL-25.01.1993 04:51.m4a
    AFTER:     1993.01.25 04:51 JPxbInkWmsLIrcbsvL.m4a

    Actual String Length: 98
    BEFORE:    jRgOBoXgWBeEcivKNKGCLSDcMdLEVIzVJdyvdiLdNBuBWNsDApKznlmroecxDtlobiVZJZHFYDPkxbgYKhdGXZIyQhhZgnzupg-13.09.2012 08:52.m4a
    AFTER:     2012.09.13 08:52 jRgOBoXgWBeEcivKNKGCLSDcMdLEVIzVJdyvdiLdNBuBWNsDApKznlmroecxDtlobiVZJZHFYDPkxbgYKhdGXZIyQhhZgnzupg.m4a

    Actual String Length: 68
    BEFORE:    eBJwbTmXdNvpFqcAwjCSHzLeuUrCsfrnCXSyYcOoUbcAdfKQxnwjrJaFPFbgBKFXvhMH-12.07.1996 09:23.m4a
    AFTER:     1996.07.12 09:23 eBJwbTmXdNvpFqcAwjCSHzLeuUrCsfrnCXSyYcOoUbcAdfKQxnwjrJaFPFbgBKFXvhMH.m4a

    Actual String Length: 97
    BEFORE:    GwkaokAfeJiWSXnJtaHMjvefVsctULbOdLuiEENWaFBomlUKjUiuNBNksffWhhltHuShCeeOnLLEUQSJysjZCHaCXkQzzQOTt-04.07.2012 08:44.m4a
    AFTER:     2012.07.04 08:44 GwkaokAfeJiWSXnJtaHMjvefVsctULbOdLuiEENWaFBomlUKjUiuNBNksffWhhltHuShCeeOnLLEUQSJysjZCHaCXkQzzQOTt.m4a

    Actual String Length: 15
    BEFORE:    QuhcQjpBmvxPYlR-01.05.1985 04:20.m4a
    AFTER:     1985.05.01 04:20 QuhcQjpBmvxPYlR.m4a

    Actual String Length: 61
    BEFORE:    owWSkNjZqLkejiAYMOUomesYViqFzdDPRlfKfXYCsmeMFUbJAvDvyYrkdYWcw-15.06.1982 03:23.m4a
    AFTER:     1982.06.15 03:23 owWSkNjZqLkejiAYMOUomesYViqFzdDPRlfKfXYCsmeMFUbJAvDvyYrkdYWcw.m4a

    Actual String Length: 96
    BEFORE:    cPSOQrWZaGsbgHfdzirSTVGhbVgOMRElHeGKCPEgbskxFVVPyxNactdhiLNUlinichtcauAKDlQBLjBfZqpodEioazBRcKVT-03.01.1990 10:32.m4a
    AFTER:     1990.01.03 10:32 cPSOQrWZaGsbgHfdzirSTVGhbVgOMRElHeGKCPEgbskxFVVPyxNactdhiLNUlinichtcauAKDlQBLjBfZqpodEioazBRcKVT.m4a

    Actual String Length: 80
    BEFORE:    dWdwRCCvZjHUVSYfxYecBTIHTpXwJNdDgBmsZhqMxdCIuPaagVXzxRnknvDBEfMlfeOtFFgqIsExqand-08.11.1986 17:47.m4a
    AFTER:     1986.11.08 17:47 dWdwRCCvZjHUVSYfxYecBTIHTpXwJNdDgBmsZhqMxdCIuPaagVXzxRnknvDBEfMlfeOtFFgqIsExqand.m4a

    Actual String Length: 16
    BEFORE:    pncfDEOhsrqDqbGu-14.09.2002 19:05.m4a
    AFTER:     2002.09.14 19:05 pncfDEOhsrqDqbGu.m4a

    Actual String Length: 82
    BEFORE:    TnizmHOXvBYzfDACMTlmgZwXcJCQZiNbcxjRveCzDtUcrBARZmVXTaJTQlxCfYYmOXxIuIhHqLIMfuFAiK-22.09.1983 18:08.m4a
    AFTER:     1983.09.22 18:08 TnizmHOXvBYzfDACMTlmgZwXcJCQZiNbcxjRveCzDtUcrBARZmVXTaJTQlxCfYYmOXxIuIhHqLIMfuFAiK.m4a

    Actual String Length: 78
    BEFORE:    pbjGauEvHnueSxqenHirXOvGXuuhlZZPvUeHXaqreqxhkvqnAIahZJQAFDJGZxkIoEJXsJgmqQnGro-11.06.1973 03:37.m4a
    AFTER:     1973.06.11 03:37 pbjGauEvHnueSxqenHirXOvGXuuhlZZPvUeHXaqreqxhkvqnAIahZJQAFDJGZxkIoEJXsJgmqQnGro.m4a

    Actual String Length: 99
    BEFORE:    RQLeDburKsGgOSFMsURBNRiwjjrhiCRQIJxNXTPHMVGyGADwPOLnQalaIpUuJmiiAQyfuSPyfjPSkJPJGVrtQEZHxxfIZuXzMyY-22.01.1992 00:56.m4a
    AFTER:     1992.01.22 00:56 RQLeDburKsGgOSFMsURBNRiwjjrhiCRQIJxNXTPHMVGyGADwPOLnQalaIpUuJmiiAQyfuSPyfjPSkJPJGVrtQEZHxxfIZuXzMyY.m4a

    Actual String Length: 29
    BEFORE:    hGltPYAkNOVOrVQRHXMgyKlpfMLZI-05.10.1989 08:34.m4a
    AFTER:     1989.10.05 08:34 hGltPYAkNOVOrVQRHXMgyKlpfMLZI.m4a

    Actual String Length: 40
    BEFORE:    weIgiPHjEXgcZkQelSNwvVncnABFUBuNyxuDoFYJ-02.01.2006 03:36.m4a
    AFTER:     2006.01.02 03:36 weIgiPHjEXgcZkQelSNwvVncnABFUBuNyxuDoFYJ.m4a

    Actual String Length: 100
    BEFORE:    xsPiBQaXAQGTHnbodCtDBPnPFTettjfwFBdnfsTWyAUMIMrvbNIFmexIeZDHLHDrLkofjOjLIxfbVAhSBIrGBzjAdvifOmkRWCay-13.03.1981 05:33.m4a
    AFTER:     1981.03.13 05:33 xsPiBQaXAQGTHnbodCtDBPnPFTettjfwFBdnfsTWyAUMIMrvbNIFmexIeZDHLHDrLkofjOjLIxfbVAhSBIrGBzjAdvifOmkRWCay.m4a

    Actual String Length: 94
    BEFORE:    PZwMESKfdqWPlaNbOGeWwmoesAJupwedEDuAHIEmeghAaNPxKkxGyazCLruejqQGmTlIGnufcRRqeNeFKlJeYxEDdROpoA-02.09.1985 11:16.m4a
    AFTER:     1985.09.02 11:16 PZwMESKfdqWPlaNbOGeWwmoesAJupwedEDuAHIEmeghAaNPxKkxGyazCLruejqQGmTlIGnufcRRqeNeFKlJeYxEDdROpoA.m4a

    Actual String Length: 57
    BEFORE:    gRxPsDGjjxYnPtXHLIOoHFOyfRCOeaEyXcEtlpGTYuTtQbygggESASUBd-26.08.1996 00:50.m4a
    AFTER:     1996.08.26 00:50 gRxPsDGjjxYnPtXHLIOoHFOyfRCOeaEyXcEtlpGTYuTtQbygggESASUBd.m4a

    Actual String Length: 23
    BEFORE:    TApMODvwbUqnLuHdsvIXvLY-03.02.1973 07:14.m4a
    AFTER:     1973.02.03 07:14 TApMODvwbUqnLuHdsvIXvLY.m4a

    Actual String Length: 15
    BEFORE:    SfpJzqLMsCLiQFC-17.09.2002 07:37.m4a
    AFTER:     2002.09.17 07:37 SfpJzqLMsCLiQFC.m4a

    Actual String Length: 63
    BEFORE:    jhOiCkDLmiRWckYcVrrGdfmmUsDCnIVXWmWhVrOBiGpCqTDrIMNZpBCeVBnjHbx-16.03.2014 00:47.m4a
    AFTER:     2014.03.16 00:47 jhOiCkDLmiRWckYcVrrGdfmmUsDCnIVXWmWhVrOBiGpCqTDrIMNZpBCeVBnjHbx.m4a

    Actual String Length: 83
    BEFORE:    hDDQyxQJWaPlUBVWHvKRmteEUgiLqvTNdRFjwzdenlFmuvhWIqmFfwEOyYWroetAgchcVLzirFDaNRkyZmc-26.02.1984 15:38.m4a
    AFTER:     1984.02.26 15:38 hDDQyxQJWaPlUBVWHvKRmteEUgiLqvTNdRFjwzdenlFmuvhWIqmFfwEOyYWroetAgchcVLzirFDaNRkyZmc.m4a

    Actual String Length: 85
    BEFORE:    KxDLPjSffsoeaXQenzSDaHNxrcbtrSuzPeabFGQuiILSjVlfjebiPKQdJftNhzOnXOpWXOyGJxvsVVowRWkmQ-06.08.1974 05:55.m4a
    AFTER:     1974.08.06 05:55 KxDLPjSffsoeaXQenzSDaHNxrcbtrSuzPeabFGQuiILSjVlfjebiPKQdJftNhzOnXOpWXOyGJxvsVVowRWkmQ.m4a

    Actual String Length: 53
    BEFORE:    mcmIUyUuFoiuGuzrpyiORXVkoBwMekJawYuGkMyxaTQDOPGvLsPOO-15.08.1984 03:02.m4a
    AFTER:     1984.08.15 03:02 mcmIUyUuFoiuGuzrpyiORXVkoBwMekJawYuGkMyxaTQDOPGvLsPOO.m4a

    Actual String Length: 39
    BEFORE:    biquEiXHaTgCaLNYgswyVaaLvUlTpfzisfvSCwY-17.10.2018 09:50.m4a
    AFTER:     2018.10.17 09:50 biquEiXHaTgCaLNYgswyVaaLvUlTpfzisfvSCwY.m4a

    Actual String Length: 29
    BEFORE:    OdPKiOFVxahFZJWesUuXkUpUvKtQG-25.07.1977 11:09.m4a
    AFTER:     1977.07.25 11:09 OdPKiOFVxahFZJWesUuXkUpUvKtQG.m4a

    Actual String Length: 20
    BEFORE:    dEXKDxIvLXwoJOFByobU-21.11.1984 10:23.m4a
    AFTER:     1984.11.21 10:23 dEXKDxIvLXwoJOFByobU.m4a

    Actual String Length: 32
    BEFORE:    zvZfQDOaOWJuNlUjynegSrdJlgltipzp-21.02.1978 22:43.m4a
    AFTER:     1978.02.21 22:43 zvZfQDOaOWJuNlUjynegSrdJlgltipzp.m4a
```

Comment: Thank you!! I was hoping that this job could be done just with a couple of shell commands but this one works perfectly as the tests show.

Comment: Glad to help. If this solves your problem I would appreciate if you could mark my answer as the solution. I would go amiss not mentioning that there are certainly unix tools that could accomplish this natively as well. One such tool would be [mmv](https://www.cgarbs.de/blog/archives/430-mmv-mass-rename-of-files-and-more!.html). It's for mass moving/renaming files using a specific wildcard syntax and I have used it before as well. I would wager though that for your use case the required command would end up being non-trivial.

Comment: Your c-program solves my problem perfectly. As I would like to motivate others to think about a pontential answer just using a shell loop with mmv and wildcards I would prefer to keep the problem open. Or would you think it is better to specify the problem further in a new question?

Comment: Yes I would strongly encourage you to provide more information. What is the environment of the problem domain, what tools would you like to use in order to solve this and what are the **definitiv** inputs for `nnn`. You are welcome to add to the list. I would advise against opening a new question since it wouldn't be a new questions rather an edit of your original. And I would like to think that's where the edit button comes into play. ;)

Btw I used **C#** and not **C**. Big difference. The latter would run natively on unix systems the former would need mono. e.g.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Unix utilities, such as `sed`, to perform the transformation of the  text.  As an experienced Ubuntu user, I would use `bash` and `sed` as follows.  As an experienced Python programmer, I could easily use it instead, especially if I needed to handle more arithmetic or needed more complicated logic around the handling of the names.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# nnn-15.10.2015 18:15.m4a
#  1   2  3   4   5
for F in *.m4a ; do
    NEWNAME=`echo $F | sed 's/\(.\+\)-\(..\)\.\(..\)\.\(....\) \(....\)\.m4a/\4-\3-\2 \5 \1.m4a/'`
    echo "Renaming '$F' to '$NEWNAME'"
    mv "$F" "$NEWNAME"
done
```

I have not tested this, but I think the pattern will be adequate for the purpose you described.  You can easily test this before running it by commenting out the `mv` line.

The key part of both solutions presented is the regular expression pattern matching.

Comment: Sorry. I am currently on a holiday trip. I will pursue with this in two weeks when I am back. Thank you.

Comment: Does it output the `DateTime` as per OPs requirement (`dd-mm-yyyy -> yyyy-mm-dd`)?

Comment: Yes it does, barring any unintentional bugs.  The pattern uses capture groups to capture the various parts of the original text, and the substitution uses references to those groups.  https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command

Comment: @woros According to [this wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)) which says `[..]by providing a command line interface to the operating system when used in conjunction with a Unix shell, such as bash (the default shell starting as of OS X Jaguar.[..]` this answer should be marked as the solution.